# Converting images to WebP - Overcoming Timeout Errors?

Tags: craft3, plugin-imageoptimize

I have over 1500 images... I'm trying to improve performance on our site and want to create WebP versions of our images.

WebP is installed - new images we upload get converted. When I resave the image variant it begins the process of conversion and optimisation of previous images but then we bump into timeout errors.

What is the best way to do this process in an efficient way? I'd be interested to know how we overcome the timeout error.

Note:

- images are in a Digital Ocean S3 bucket.
- we are using the incredible imageOptimize plugin
- we host the site on Laravel Forge

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the discussion on this [pull request](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-imageoptimize/pull/150). Since ImageOptimize uses regular Craft transforms, it's likely that this is something in the AWS S3 plugin.

Indeed, there's an issue [400 Bad Request: token expired](https://github.com/craftcms/aws-s3/issues/22) that appears to be identical. If there's something I can/should be doing to renew the token, I'll definitely make that change.

I'm pending information at the moment.

EDIT: I believe I have found and fixed the issue in the `aws-s3` package from P&T; I created a [pull request](https://github.com/craftcms/aws-s3/pull/61) to address it.

Comment: Interesting - we are using the DigitalOcean Spaces Volume plugin which is based on the first-party AWS S3 Volume for Craft - it's likely you have fixed the issue but in another plugin. https://github.com/vaersaagod/dospaces

Comment: Are you using the CLI command in ImageOptimize for this? If not, I'd recommend trying it. If you still have issues, perhaps contact the plugin author?

Comment: I think I did try - I'll have another go and see how we get on.